# ReportViewer - MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

Boa tarde,

Utilizo o VisualStudio 2015 Community em um Windows 10 x64 e estou encontrando o seguinte problema ao rodar o debug de um projeto Windows Form Application:

```
    System.MethodAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233072
  Message=Falha no método 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport..ctor()' ao tentar acessar o método 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore..ctor()'.
  Source=Sistema
  StackTrace:
       em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport..ctor() na C:\Projetos\VisualStudio\Sistema\Sistema\Beans\GuiaSadt.cs:linha 0
       em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.CreateLocalReport() na C:\Projetos\VisualStudio\Sistema\Sistema\Beans\GuiaSadt.cs:linha 0
       em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.Reset() na C:\Projetos\VisualStudio\Sistema\Sistema\Beans\GuiaSadt.cs:linha 0
       em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer..ctor() na C:\Projetos\VisualStudio\Sistema\Sistema\Beans\GuiaSadt.cs:linha 0
       em Sistema.FrmPrincipal.FrmPrincipal_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:\Projetos\VisualStudio\Sistema\Sistema\FrmPrincipal.cs:linha 181
       em System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Estou usando o Control ReportViewer dentro de um Form sem mais nada nele e acontece este erro.

Está faltando alguma referência ou alguma configuração em meu projeto?
Grato.

**EDIT:**
Onde ocorre o erro é o trecho a seguir:

```
this.reportViewer1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
```

Comment: Tem mais informações do erro?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho infelizmente não, é só isso que aparece no painel de detalhes da excessão, tem alguma outra informação que eu possa colocar aqui ou uma imagem?..agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Qual é o método do reportviewer q esta dado erro?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho editei a pergunta com o trecho que lança a exception

Comment: Vc esta inicializando o objeto no evento load?

Comment: Este `this.reportViewer1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();` é o conteúdo da linha 181?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Quando eu arrasto o control pro form, automaticamente é criado no evento Load do form o código `this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();` que é a linha 181 já o `new ReportViewer()` é chado a partir do `InitializeComponents()` do construtor do form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que estava ocorrendo era com o ILMerge. 
Como o ILMerge junta com o .exe as DLL's utilizadas pelo projeto o ReportViewer não achava a referencia o que causava o erro. 
Removendo o ILMerge do projeto tudo voltou a funcionar.